# css div inner border only

Tags: css, html, border

I hope someone can help me.  I am trying to get to this:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

[image]

And below is my current html.  How can I show the border on just the inner portion of the divs (like in the first screenshot)?  Also, how do I make the height and width of each div a square (not rectangular)?  Is it better to use an html table or is this possible using divs?  The html code is dynamically being generated, so I cannot just add the right/left border on the individual divs.

```
<div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">                               
<div style="float: left;width: 14%;background-color: #CCCCCC;border-right: 1px solid black;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">S</span>
    <br/>
    0&#45;0
</div>
<div style="float: left;width: 14%;background-color: #CCCCCC;border-right: 1px solid black;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">M</span>
    <br/>
    5&#45;7
</div>      
<div style="float: left;width: 14%;background-color: #CCCCCC;border-right: 1px solid black;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">T</span>
    <br/>
    5&#45;7
</div>      
<div style="float: left;width: 14%;background-color: #CCCCCC;border-right: 1px solid black;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">W</span>
    <br/>
    5&#45;7
</div>      
<div style="float: left;width: 14%;background-color: #CCCCCC;border-right: 1px solid black;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">R</span>
    <br/>
    5&#45;7
</div>      
<div style="float: left;width: 14%;background-color: #CCCCCC;border-right: 1px solid black;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">F</span>
    <br/>
    7&#45;5
</div>      
<div style="float: left;width: 14%;background-color: #CCCCCC;border-right: 1px solid black;">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">S</span>
    <br/>
    0&#45;0
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to achieve this? http://jsfiddle.net/5WY82/

Comment: Almost - the last cell has a right border.  Also, the cells are not a perfect square.  Last, since the html code is dynamically being generated I cannot simply remove the border-right style on the last div.  Is there a way to dynamically set the borders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
}
span {
    display:block;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    height:40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
.box.act {
    background-color:white;
}
.box:first-child {
    border:none;
}
.box > span:first-child {
    font-weight:bold;
}
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <span>S</span>
        <span>0&#45;0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <span>M</span>
        <span>5&#45;7</span>
    </div>      
    <div class="box">
        <span>T</span>
        <span>5&#45;7</span>
    </div>      
    <div class="box">
        <span>W</span>
        <span>5&#45;7</span>
    </div>      
    <div class="box">
        <span>R</span>
        <span>5&#45;7</span>
    </div>      
    <div class="box act">
        <span>F</span>
        <span>7&#45;5</span>
    </div>      
    <div class="box">
        <span>S</span>
        <span>0&#45;0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: has the main-wrapper to be 100% ?

Comment: The crux here is the `:first-child` selector.

Answer (score 0):

don't add border on the last div.

use padding to establish widths and heigts